# Remove part of a file extension in java

Tags: java

I want to remove part of a file extension in java to just get the actual txt file name selected. I have a FileDialog to browse through files and the selected file is then stored in a variable...

```
  // take chosen f name.
  chosen_f_name = txtFile.getText();
  System.out.println(chosen_f_name);
```

which outputs...

```
  C:\Users\username\Documents\Project\projectname\data_file.txt
```

How would I remove everything **before and including** the last `\` using the chosen_f_name variable declared to just get the `data_file.txt` part?

Comment: What type is `txtFile` and how do you use the `FileDialog`?

Comment: I would probably use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Also, do not hard-code the backslash as separator, this makes the program platform-depentent. Use `File.separator` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String chosen_f_name = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Project\\projectname\\data_file.txt";
        System.out.println(chosen_f_name);
        String fileName = chosen_f_name.substring(chosen_f_name.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        System.out.println(fileName);

        // Alternatively, you can use File.separator to avoid hard coded platform
        // dependent separator e.g.
        URL location = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        String file = location.getFile()+"Main.java";
        System.out.println(file);
        String fName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
        System.out.println(fName);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\Project\projectname\data_file.txt
data_file.txt
/Users/arvind.avinash/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/bin/Main.java
Main.java
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
String resulted_name = chosen_f_name.substring(chosen_f_name.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar)+1);
```

Comment: Simple, effective, cross-platform, beginner friendly: perfect!